# unresolved external symbol _png_init_io referenced in function _pixReadStreamPng

Tags: windows, visual-c++, libpng, leptonica

Under Windows 7, I have dowloaded and unzipped [leptonica.zip](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica), and then followed the steps (in order to run Cmake successfully) :

```
cd leptonica
mkdir build
cd build
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\OCR\additionalLibs\zlib-1.2.8\build\Debug;C:\OCR\additionalLibs\zlib-1.2.8\build;C:\OCR\additionalLibs\zlib-1.2.8
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\OCR\additionalLibs\lpng143;C:\OCR\additionalLibs\lpng143\build\Debug;C:\OCR\additionalLibs\lpng143\build
cmake ..
```

After that, I obtain:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24213.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24213.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find GIF (missing:  GIF_LIBRARY GIF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY)
-- Found ZLIB: C:/OCR/additionalLibs/zlib-1.2.8/build/Debug/zlibd.lib (found ver
sion "1.2.8")
-- Found PNG: C:/OCR/additionalLibs/lpng143/build/Debug/png14d.lib (found versio
n "1.4.3")
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "0.
26")
-- Checking for module 'libwebp'
--   No package 'libwebp' found
-- Checking for module 'libopenjp2'
--   No package 'libopenjp2' found
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for include file memory.h
-- Looking for include file memory.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for include file strings.h
-- Looking for include file strings.h - not found
-- Looking for include file string.h
-- Looking for include file string.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for include file openjpeg-2.0/openjpeg.h
-- Looking for include file openjpeg-2.0/openjpeg.h - not found
-- Looking for include file openjpeg-2.1/openjpeg.h
-- Looking for include file openjpeg-2.1/openjpeg.h - not found
-- Looking for include file openjpeg-2.2/openjpeg.h
-- Looking for include file openjpeg-2.2/openjpeg.h - not found
-- Looking for fmemopen
-- Looking for fmemopen - not found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/OCR/leptonica-master/build
```

libjpeg,libtiff and libgif are deliberately not considered since I am only interested to manage png files.
The cmake command outputs a `leptonica.sln` solution file.
I then compile the solution file on visual studio (in order to find the headers file `zlib.h ; zconf.h; png.h; pngconfig.h` I have modified the INCLUDE directories, adding: C:\OCR\additionalLibs\zlib-1.2.8;C:\OCR\additionalLibs\lpng143).

But the solution does not compile due to the errors:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _png_init_io referenced in function _pixReadStreamPng    leptonica   
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _png_init_io referenced in function _pixReadStreamPng    leptonica
```

The error comes from the file `pngio.h` , which in `pixReadStreamPng` calls the function `png_init_io` , defined in `png.h`. Seems like the implementation of the function is not found, are there additional libraries which should be implemented? Where is `png_init_io` implemented?

Comment: It's implemented in png.c.  But it's guarded by #ifdef PNG_STDIO_SUPPORTED, which you've possibly not defined.  See comments in png.c

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson please write it as an answer, it solved the problem for me! =) thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again but what is the fix? I tried to `#define PNG_STDIO_SUPPORTED 1` in my file before the import but it's still not working

Answer (score 4):

It's implemented in libpng's png.c, but it's guarded by #ifdef PNG_STDIO_SUPPORTED, which you've possibly not defined. See comments in png.c:

```
#  ifdef PNG_STDIO_SUPPORTED
/* Initialize the default input/output functions for the PNG file.  If you
 * use your own read or write routines, you can call either png_set_read_fn()
 * or png_set_write_fn() instead of png_init_io().  If you have defined
 * PNG_NO_STDIO or otherwise disabled PNG_STDIO_SUPPORTED, you must use a
 * function of your own because "FILE *" isn't necessarily available.
 */
void PNGAPI
png_init_io(png_structrp png_ptr, png_FILE_p fp)
{
   png_debug(1, "in png_init_io");

   if (png_ptr == NULL)
      return;

   png_ptr->io_ptr = (png_voidp)fp;
}
#  endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncheck PNG_NO_STDIO flag in CMake configuration

[image: CMake Flags of libpng]